# how to catch response in POST method in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, web-services, angular7

I am working with Angular 7 and want to catch the response back that the data is saved or not.

In my web service code, I am setting up the status `"Success"` if data is saved successfully and `"Unsuccessful"` if data is not saved to the Database.

I want to give an alert to the UI that is sent by the web service.

below is my UI code to call web service to save the data into DB.

```
return this.httpService.post(this.baseUrl + this.serviceUrl + 'saveData', body, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError('addData', data))
            );
```

can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: *In my web service code, I am setting up the status "Success" if data is saved successfully and "Unsuccessful" if data is not saved to the Database.* If you want to use the standard error mechanisms of observables, then you need to respect the semantics of http, and return an HTTP response with an error status. Not a successful response with status 200 OK and  a body saying "Unsuccessful".

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple approach that I used where servicer esponse is captured and displayed in a modal dialog [using material design] - reusable component ( pseudo code pointers below, update as required ):

```
this.backEndService.myAPI(serviceRequest)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.postProcess(res as string);
            },
                (error) => {
                    //handle error
                }
            );
```

Continued logic to handle response:

```
 private postProcess(generatedResponse: string) {
        //do things like set loading to false etc..
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent, {
            data: generatedResponse
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            // nothing in my case
        });
    }
```

**modal-dialog.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: ...,
    templateUrl: ..,
    styleUrls: [...]
})


export class ModalDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalDialogComponent >,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public generatedResponse: string) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }


    public onOk() {
        console.log('onOk');
        this.dialogRef.close({
            data: {
                closed: true
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**modal-dialog.component.html**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>....</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>
    <section fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <mat-card fxFlex="500px" fxFlex.xs="100%">
            <mat-card-title>Title
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div fxLayout="column wrap" fxLayoutGap="40px grid">

                    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                        <div fxFlex="65%"><strong>Status</strong>{{generatedResponse}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </section>

</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="onOk()">OK</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: Subscribing inside subscribes is not a very nice practice, nor it looks clean, instead you should take advantage of all the rxjs operators, for this case, the switchMap is a good way to go. If the code needs to be parallel you could use zip instead.

Comment: @Shakawkaw, thanks for the tip, would explore this.